# Resolving Fortran compilation error for `call itime(now)`, `error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit types`

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am not a Fortran programmer at all, but I have a project where the original code was written in Fortran. I believe it is Fortran 77. The issue is that I am trying to compile the code, but I am getting all sorts of errors. I am pretty sure that this code should compile smoothly, since it has been tested a bunch by the original author. However, for some reason when I compile the code, I get errors. Unfortunately, I can't track down the original author.

My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the compilation. So if someone can set
me straight on that, that would be wonderful.

I have the code below. I tried using a few different compilation strings. NOTE: There is an additional file called `inputnewrate.txt` that has some settings for this file. I have include that additional file below as well.

`fort77 -c discrete.f`

`f77 -c discrete.f`

`gfortran -c discrete.f`

Here is the code--it is pretty long. And then the error message is below that.

```
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      program implicit
      implicit none
      integer i,j,n,l,pic,screen,guy,burgsatloc(512,512),k,
     $     robbyloc(512,512),outcome,newburgs(512,512),willplace,
     $     totalguys,in,jn,totalburgs(512,512),neighbors(512,512,4,2)
      integer*4 today(3),now(3)
      double precision A(512,512),t/0.0d0/,dt,tint,gamma,Bbar,
     $     tmax,omega,theta,eta,A0,disp/0.0d0/,placeprob,
     $     robprob,Bavg,B(512,512),rbar,moveprob(5),newB(512,512)
      real ran2,rtmp

      call idate(today)
      call itime(now)
      rtmp=ran2(-(today(1)+today(2)+today(3)+now(1)+now(2)+now(3)))
      call input(l,tmax,tint,dt,omega,theta,eta,A0,
     $     gamma)
      placeprob=gamma*dt
      Bbar=theta*gamma/omega
      rbar=placeprob/(1.0d0-exp(-(A0+Bbar)*dt))
      call initialize(burgsatloc,B,l,pic,screen,rbar,Bbar)
      willplace=int(placeprob)
      placeprob=placeprob-dble(willplace)
      call getneighbors(l,neighbors)
      do i=1,l
         do j=1,l
            robbyloc(i,j)=0
            totalburgs(i,j)=0
         enddo
      enddo
      do while (t .LT. tmax)
         totalguys=0
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               totalguys=totalguys+burgsatloc(i,j)
               newburgs(i,j)=0
               robbyloc(i,j)=0
               A(i,j)=B(i,j)+A0
            enddo
         enddo
         if (t .GE. tint*disp) then
            call output(A,burgsatloc,t,l,pic,screen,A0,Bbar)
            write(*,*) 'totalguys=',totalguys
            disp=disp+1.0d0
         endif  
c     See if burglars burgle.  If so, remove them.
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               n=burgsatloc(i,j)
               if (n .NE. 0) then
                  robprob=1.0d0-exp(-A(i,j)*dt)
               endif
               do guy=1,n
                  call probcheck(robprob,1,outcome)
                  if (outcome .EQ. 1) then
                     robbyloc(i,j)=robbyloc(i,j)+1
                     totalburgs(i,j)=totalburgs(i,j)+1
                     burgsatloc(i,j)=burgsatloc(i,j)-1
                  endif
               enddo
            enddo
         enddo
c     Now, move the burglars that didn't burgle.
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               n=burgsatloc(i,j)
               if (n .NE. 0) then
                  call getmoveprob(i,j,A,neighbors,moveprob)
               endif
               do guy=1,n
                  call probcheck(moveprob,4,outcome)
c                  if (outcome .NE. 5) then
                     in=neighbors(i,j,outcome,1)
                     jn=neighbors(i,j,outcome,2)
c                  else
c                     in=i
c                     jn=j
c                  endif
                  newburgs(in,jn)=newburgs(in,jn)+1
               enddo
            enddo
         enddo
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               burgsatloc(i,j)=newburgs(i,j)+willplace
            enddo
         enddo
c     Now, loop over each location and update the A there and place
c     new burglars
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               call findavg(i,j,neighbors,B,Bavg)
               newB(i,j)=((1.0d0-eta)*B(i,j)+eta*Bavg)*
     $              (1.0d0-omega*dt)+theta*dble(robbyloc(i,j))
               call probcheck(placeprob,1,outcome)
               if (outcome .EQ. 1) then
                  burgsatloc(i,j)=burgsatloc(i,j)+1
               endif
            enddo
         enddo
         do i=1,l
            do j=1,l
               B(i,j)=newB(i,j)
            enddo
         enddo
         t=t+dt
c    write(*,*) 'time=',t
      enddo
      call PGCLOS

      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine input(l,tmax,tint,dt,omega,theta,eta,A0,
     $     gamma)
      implicit none
      integer l,file
      double precision tmax,tint,dt,omega,theta,eta,A0,gamma
c     Allows for interactive selection of properties
      file=20
      open(unit=file,file="inputnewrate.txt")
      read(file,*) l
      read(file,*) tmax
      read(file,*) tint
      read(file,*) dt
      read(file,*) omega
      read(file,*) A0
      read(file,*) theta
      read(file,*) eta
      call itime(now)
      read(file,*) gamma
      close(file)
c      nbar=1.0d0
c      A0=r0/(1.0d0-r0)
c      beta=lambda/rbar*(rbar/(1.0d0-rbar)-A0)
c      delta=beta/nbar
c      dt=(1.0d0/dble(l-1))**2/D
c      placeprob=rbar*nbar*dt

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine initialize(burgsatloc,B,l,pic,screen,rbar,Bbar)
      implicit none
      integer l,pic,screen,i,j,k,PGOPEN,burgsatloc(512,*),nbar,outc
      real rand,red,green,blue
      double precision B(512,*),rbar,Bbar,frac

      nbar=int(rbar)
      frac=rbar-dble(nbar)
      write(*,*) nbar,frac,Bbar
      do i=1,l
         do j=1,l
            burgsatloc(i,j)=nbar
            call probcheck(frac,1,outc)
            if (outc .EQ. 1) then
               burgsatloc(i,j)=burgsatloc(i,j)+1
            endif
            B(i,j)=Bbar
         enddo
      enddo
c      burgsatloc((l+1)/2,(l+1)/2)=10000
c     Now open the PGPLOT display
c      pic=PGOPEN('crime#.gif/gif')
      pic=PGOPEN('/xserv')
      if (pic .LE. 0) stop
c      if (screen .LE. 0) stop
      call PGPAP(5.0,1.0)  
      call PGASK(.FALSE.)
      call PGSCIR(16,94)
      do i=16,42
         red=1.0
         green=1.0/26.0*real(i-16)
         blue=0.0
         call PGSCR(i,red,green,blue)
      enddo
      do i=43,55
         red=max(1.0-1.0/13.0*real(i-42),0.0)
         green=1.0
         blue=0.0
         call PGSCR(i,red,green,blue)
      enddo
      do i=56,68
         red=0.0
      call itime(now)
         green=1.0
         blue=1.0/13.0*real(i-55)
         call PGSCR(i,red,green,blue)
      enddo
      do i=69,81
         red=0.0
         green=max(1.0-1.0/13.0*real(i-68),0.0)
         blue=1.0
         call PGSCR(i,red,green,blue)
      enddo
      do i=82,94
         red=1.0/13.0*real(i-81)
         green=0.0
         blue=1.0
         call PGSCR(i,red,green,blue)
      enddo

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine output(A,burgsatloc,t,l,pic,screen,A0,Bbar)
      implicit none
      integer l,pic,screen,i,j,lengtht,burgsatloc(512,*)
      character*7 tchar
      double precision t,A(512,*),A0,Bbar
      real dx,trans(6),minmum,maxmum,crime(512,512)

      dx=1.0/real(l)
      trans(1)=-dx/2.0
      trans(2)=dx
      trans(3)=0.0
      trans(4)=trans(1)
      trans(5)=trans(3)
      trans(6)=trans(2)
c         maxmum=2.0*real(rbar)
c         minmum=0.0
      minmum=real(A0)
      maxmum=real(2.0d0*Bbar+A0)
      do i=1,l
     do j=1,l
c       crime(i,j)=real(min(burgsatloc(i,j),1))
            crime(i,j)=real(A(i,j))
     enddo
      enddo
c      call minmax(crime,l,minmum,maxmum)
c      if (minmum .EQ. maxmum) then
c         if (minmum .EQ. 0.0) then
c            maxmum=1.0
c            minmum=-1.0
c         else
c            maxmum=1.01*maxmum
c            minmum=minmum/1.01
c         endif
c      endif
c      write(*,*) minmum,maxmum
      call PGBBUF()
      call PGNUMB(int(t*1.0d2),-2,1,tchar,lengtht)      
c      call PGSLCT(pic)
      call PGENV(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1,0)
      call PGLAB('x','y','A(x,y,t), Time='
     $     //tchar(1:lengtht))
      call PGIMAG(crime,512,512,1,l,1,l,maxmum,minmum,trans)
c      call PGSLCT(screen)
c      call PGENV(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1,0)
c      call PGLAB('x','y','crime rate(x,y,t), Time='
c     $     //tchar(1:lengtht))
c      call PGIMAG(crime,1024,1024,1,n,1,n,maxmum,minmum,trans)     
      call PGEBUF()

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine probcheck(problist,length,outcome)
      implicit none
      integer length,outcome,i
      double precision problist(*),currentprob
      real ran2,rtmp
      logical looking

      rtmp=ran2(13)
      if (length .EQ. 1) then
         if (dble(rtmp) .LE. problist(1)) then
            outcome=1
         else
            outcome=0
         endif
      else
         looking=.TRUE.
         i=1
         do while (looking .AND. i .LE. length-1)
            if (i .EQ. 1) then
               currentprob=problist(1)
            else
               currentprob=currentprob+problist(i)
            endif
            if (rtmp .LE. currentprob) then
               outcome=i
               looking=.FALSE.
            else
               i=i+1
            endif
         enddo
         if (looking) outcome=length
      endif
      
      return
      end


cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine getmoveprob(i,j,A,neighbors,moveprob)
      implicit none
      integer i,j,neighbors(512,512,4,*),k,in,jn
      double precision A(512,*),moveprob(*),sum

      sum=0.0d0
      do k=1,4
         in=neighbors(i,j,k,1)
         jn=neighbors(i,j,k,2)
         moveprob(k)=A(in,jn)
         sum=sum+moveprob(k)
      enddo
c      moveprob(5)=A(i,j)
c      sum=sum+moveprob(5)
      if (sum .NE. 0.0d0) then
c         do k=1,5
         do k=1,4
            moveprob(k)=moveprob(k)/sum
         enddo
      else
c         do k=1,5
         do k=1,4
            moveprob(k)=0.25d0
         enddo
      endif

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine getneighbors(l,neighbors)
      implicit none
      integer i,j,l,neighbors(512,512,4,*)

      do i=1,l
         do j=1,l
            neighbors(i,j,1,1)=i
            if (j .NE. l) then
               neighbors(i,j,1,2)=j+1
            else
               neighbors(i,j,1,2)=1
            endif
            if (i .NE. l) then
               neighbors(i,j,2,1)=i+1
            else
               neighbors(i,j,2,1)=1
            endif
            neighbors(i,j,2,2)=j
            neighbors(i,j,3,1)=i
            if (j .NE. 1) then
               neighbors(i,j,3,2)=j-1
            else
               neighbors(i,j,3,2)=l
            endif
            if (i .NE. 1) then
               neighbors(i,j,4,1)=i-1
            else
               neighbors(i,j,4,1)=l
            endif
            neighbors(i,j,4,2)=j
         enddo
      enddo

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine findavg(i,j,neighbors,B,Bavg)
      implicit none
      integer i,j,neighbors(512,512,4,*),k,in,jn
      double precision B(512,*),Bavg

      Bavg=0.0d0
      do k=1,4
         in=neighbors(i,j,k,1)
         jn=neighbors(i,j,k,2)
         Bavg=Bavg+B(in,jn)
      enddo
      Bavg=Bavg/4.0d0

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      subroutine minmax(z,l,min,max)
      implicit none
      integer l,i,j
      real z(512,*),min,max

      min=z(1,1)
      max=z(1,1)
      do i=1,l
         do j=1,l
            if (z(i,j) .GT. max) max=z(i,j)
            if (z(i,j) .LT. min) min=z(i,j)
         enddo
      enddo

      return
      end

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      function ran2(idummy)
      implicit none
      integer idum,im1,im2,imm1,ia1,ia2,iq1,iq2,ir1,ir2,ntab,ndiv,idummy
      real ran2,am,eps,rnmx
      parameter (im1=2147483563,im2=2147483399,am=1./im1,imm1=im1-1,
     $     ia1=40014,ia2=40692,iq1=53668,iq2=52774,ir1=12211,
     $     ir2=3791,ntab=32,ndiv=1+imm1/ntab,eps=1.2e-7,rnmx=1.-eps)
      integer idum2,j,k,iv(ntab),iy
      save iv,iy,idum2
      data idum2/123456789/, iv/ntab*0/, iy/0/
      
      idum=idummy
      if (idum .le. 0) then
         idum=max(-idum,1)
         idum2=idum
         do j=ntab+8,1,-1
            k=idum/iq1
            idum=ia1*(idum-k*iq1)-k*ir1
            if (idum .lt. 0) idum=idum+im1
            if (j .le. ntab) iv(j)=idum
         enddo
         iy=iv(1)
      endif
      k=idum/iq1
      idum=ia1*(idum-k*iq1)-k*ir1
      if (idum .lt. 0) idum=idum+im1
      k=idum2/iq2
      idum2=ia2*(idum2-k*iq2)-k*ir2
      if (idum2 .lt. 0) idum2=idum2+im2
      j=1+iy/ndiv
      iy=iv(j)-idum2
      iv(j)=idum
      if (iy .lt. 1) iy=iy+imm1
      ran2=min(am*iy,rnmx)

      return
      end
```

Further, there is a file called `inputnewrate.txt` which has settings for the model. I believe this is the file referenced in the `input` subroutine around line 114.

```
128 length of side 420
364.0   Simulation time 2174
1.0 Time between outputs
0.01    dt 0.01
0.06667 omega 0.06667
0.13425 a0 (0.13425 for subcritical, 0.03333 for standard)
0.2194  theta 0.05561 is for nbar=1, gets bigger for smaller nbar (0.2194 for subcritical) 48.0491178 5.574
0.006   eta (0.006 for subcritical) 0.02
0.01998 gamma 0.1998 is for nbar=1, gets smaller for smaller nbar 0.000023124 0.00131 (0.02 for subcritical)
0.0 f, the fraction of simulated events to be replaced with the real events



0.03333 a0 (0.13425 for subcritical, 0.03333 for standard)
3.97406 theta 0.05561 is for nbar=1, gets bigger for smaller nbar (0.02194 for subcritical) 48.0491178 5.574
0.01    eta (0.006 for subcritical) 0.02
0.0018374   gamma 0.1998 is for nbar=1, gets smaller for smaller nbar 0.000023124 0.00131
0.90    f, the fraction of simulated events to be replaced with the real events



0.0714  omega 0.0714
0.0 r0 0.00033
0.00000714  rbar 0.0025
0.8 eta 0.02
1.0 nbar 0.1
```

The error messages I am hitting are:

```
fort77 -c discrete.f
   MAIN implicit:
Error on line 8: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
Warning on line 111: local variable k never used
   input:
Error on line 130: Declaration error for now: attempt to use undefined variable
   initialize:
Error on line 186: Declaration error for now: attempt to use undefined variable
Warning on line 205: local variable k never used
Warning on line 205: local variable rand never used
   output:
   probcheck:
   getmoveprob:
   getneighbors:
   findavg:
   minmax:
   ran2:
/usr/bin/fort77: aborting compilation
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Based upon the help of the commenters, one thought is that this might be Oracle Fortran. I can't confirm that yet, but I can try to compile using Oracle Fortran.

Comment: I just looked at the error for line 8, probable causes `t/0.0d0/` (and in the next line the `disp`). Remove the `/0.0d0/` parts and add before the `call idate(today)` the line `t = 0` (and `disp = 0`). I don't like counting so where are the lines 130 and 186?

Comment: The code is not close to being Fortran 77 code, so please use a compiler which supports the language standard and the non-standard extensions the code uses.

Comment: @francescalus Oh so this is not Fortran 77. Is it an older or newer Fortran? I tried using `gfortran` which I believe is for modern fortran, but that did not work either. It was written like in 2012 or something.

Comment: @albert Oh nice. Yeah. let me try that. Okay, for line 130, it is in the `input` subroutine and it says `call itime(now)`. Line 186 is in the `initialize` subroutine and it also says `call itime(now)`. Lines 205 is just the end of the `initialize` subroutine, but that is just a warning.

Comment: It uses (many) features that were not introduced until Fortran 90, but also uses extensions which are not part of any version of Fortran.  Line 7 (`integer*4 ...`) in particular is not valid Fortran. But more crucially that line 8 is very much not.

Comment: @francescalus Hmm. So seems like your saying I should try compliers that are Fortran 90 or later. I can look for newer fortran compilers, like Flang and others. Basically just try them all until I find one that works :).

Comment: @francescalus okay, I was looking at what you said about `integer*4`. Interestingly enough it came up on the manual page for Oracle Fortran 77. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365d4b/index.html . Is there an Oracle fortran ?

Comment: I would just use gfortran like you did and see what errors there are are fix those. Which version of gfortran are you using?

Comment: Try Intel's Fortran compiler.  It's the latest incarnation of a series of compilers which date back to the 60s and includes capabilities to work with all sorts of non-standard extensions to the language. Including, if I remember correctly, the kind of construct in line 8 of the code shown which causes the other compilers to barf.  I wouldn't waste my time trying to make it work using Oracle's Fortran compiler it has fallen so far behind the state of the art.  If you can't get the Intel compiler, use `gfortran` and fix the problems.

Comment: Unless you have other files as part of this project, it's also likely that the project is relying on non-standard intrinsics `idate` and `itime` (those lines you identify). The Intel compiler doesn't provide these intrinsics, but they are available in the intrinsic module `ifport`, so if trying with ifort you'll need to modify the code to use that module. (There may be similar issues elsewhere in the code.)

Comment: @francescalus I was looking into `IFPORT` like you suggested, with the  intel compiler. Seems like I should use the compile instruction `ifort -fpp -D IFORT discrete.f `. Do I need `IFPORT` for `gfortran`? You are correct that the errors that exist in `gfortran` and intel compiler are about `call itime(now)`. The message is `This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NOW]`. So in the `input` subroutine, do I need to explicitly dimension a `now` variable?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks for the tip about the Intel compiler. I was looking at Oracle and it was a mess. I will try with both Intel and `gfortran`.

Comment: @albert . I check and am using `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`. Is that a good version? Seems to be behind the latest releases. Do you think I should upgrade?

Comment: Okay @all, I got it to work. I just have to add the line `integer*4 today(3), now(3)` to the subroutines where the errors were occurring. After that I used the compile string
`ifort -fpp -D IFORT discrete-kb-edits.f -lpgplot` . And then it worked :). I also got it working on `gfortran` as well. Yeah. So I am able to run this code now. Thanks to everyone for all of their help.

Comment: I think the version is OK, though updating  probably wouldn't hurt (as there are newer versions 12.1 and for the 9 series there is 9.5,https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html).

Comment: @albert thanks. Yeah, I will upgrade and give it a try. I still see some compile errors on `gfortran` that are not present with `ifort`. So maybe and upgrade will fix that.

Comment: If the compiler can't find `idate()` although the function might be linked in from a library, then you need to provide an interface for the function. This mean writing a `interface .. end interface` block that contains the function header.

Comment: @JAlex thanks for the tip here. I was able to get the code to compile using `ifort` and it seems to work. I believe I was getting warnings on the `idate()` lines, so perhaps using your `interface` block will resolve that. Thanks for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: @krishnab - I just faced a very similar issue with one of the MKL samples which called the function `DSCND()` for timing, and it was defined inside `Lapack` library.  The warning I got was of a unresolved external, which goes away with an interface block. **As a rule functions outside modules need interface blocks**.

Comment: @JAlex yeah, I have a boat load of fluid dynamics codes that I have to go through in Fortran, and Fortran is still new to me. Thanks for the tip on the interface blocks, otherwise I would not know where to look for the answer to any errors that come up.